# Python script video system will not initialize

Tags: python, video, initialization

Here's a copy of the script. The error is on line 25.

```
import os, sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

if not pygame.font: print 'Warning, fonts disabled'
if not pygame.mixer: print 'Warning, sound disabled'

class PyManMain:
    """The Main PyMan Class - This class handles the main 
    initialization and creating of the Game."""

    def __init__(self, width=640,height=480):
        """Initialize"""
        """Initialize PyGame"""
        pygame.init()
        """Set the window Size"""
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        """Create the Screen"""
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))

        def MainLoop(self):
            """This is the Main Loop of the Game"""
    while 1:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
                if __name__ == "__main__":
                    MainWindow = PyManMain()
    MainWindow.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some indentation problem, try with this code :

```
import os, sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

if not pygame.font: print 'Warning, fonts disabled'
if not pygame.mixer: print 'Warning, sound disabled'

class PyManMain:
    """The Main PyMan Class - This class handles the main 
    initialization and creating of the Game."""

    def __init__(self, width=640,height=480):
        """Initialize"""
        """Initialize PyGame"""
        pygame.init()
        """Set the window Size"""
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        """Create the Screen"""
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
        print self.screen

    def MainLoop(self):
        """This is the Main Loop of the Game"""
        while 1:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainWindow = PyManMain()
    MainWindow.MainLoop()
```